# Why in some cells is GTP made in citric acid cycle and in some ATP?

Tags: mitochondria

In many  animals GTP is produced in citric acid cycle. While in  plants,bacteria and some animals ATP is produced. Why is this so ? What is the advantage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This step is catalyzed by succinyl-CoA synthase which has two different isoforms- one which produces GTP while the other produced ATP.
It seems from [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15234968) study that predominantly anabolic tissues prefer the GTP-producing form whereas the predominantly catabolic tissues use the ATP-producing from. 
In the same paper they discuss that GTP is important for protein synthesis and it is also involved in production of phospho-enolpyruvate by PEP-carboxykinase in mitochondria; therefore playing an important role in anabolic processes.